# Loop da função retorna só um valor

Tags: php, html

Estou tentando pegar dados de uma pagina online só que o código está apresentando um problema, ele não consegue processar todos itens do modo `POST`, dentro do `foreach`.

Mesmo que eu coloque os itens em lista só pega o ultimo item postado. Gostaria de saber como posso solucionar esse problema.

Codigo

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="pegavideo.php">
  <p>
    <textarea name="urls" id="urls" cols="100" rows="20"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="gerar" id="gerar" value="Gerar urls do Super Animes" />
  </p>
</form>
<?php 

function pegarDados ($valorUrl) {
   $url = $valorUrl;
   $html = file_get_contents($url);
   $doc = new DOMDocument();
   @$doc->loadHTML($html);
   $tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('source');
   foreach ($tags as $tag) { return $tag->getAttribute('src').'<br/>';}
}


$dados = $_POST['urls'];
$valoresUrl = explode("\n",$dados);
for($i = 0; $i < count($valoresUrl); $i++) {
   echo pegarDados($valoresUrl[$i]);
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Você está tirando  o \n com o trim e tentando fazer o explode com um \n que removeu anteriormente

Comment: Pronto corrigi essa parte que você mencionou.

Comment: Que erro está a receber

Comment: O que esta acontecendo e o seguinte, se eu colocar uma lista de links, só retorna um único resultado. Ou seja se eu colocar por exemplo 10 links só retorna uma unica url.

Comment: Faça um print_r de $valoresUrl para ver o que está passando no for

Comment: Eu coloquei para teste os numeros 1,2,3 e deu esse resultado
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 ) Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 ) Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 )

Comment: Tente colocar 3 URL separados por enter o que dá o print_r

Comment: Array ( [0] => https://drive.google.com/1 [1] => https://drive.google.com/2 ) Array ( [0] => https://drive.google.com/1 [1] => https://drive.google.com/2 ) Literalmente esta repetindo o mesmo resultado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui tem um problema:

```
 function pegarDados ($valorUrl) {
    $url = $valorUrl;
    $html = file_get_contents($url);
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($html);
    $tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('source');
    /// este foreach nunca vai sair da primeira iteração:
    foreach ($tags as $tag) { return $tag->getAttribute('src').'<br/>';}
 }
```

Quando o `foreach` acontecer, o `return` já sairá da função retornando somente o primeiro `src`. Se quer retornar uma lista separada por `<br/>` precisa de algo assim:

```
   ...
   $tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('source');
   $lista = '';
   foreach ($tags as $tag) { $lista .= $tag->getAttribute('src').'<br/>';}
   return $lista;
 }
```

Desta forma, o foreach a cada iteração vai acrescentar o `src` desejado em $lista, e depois do loop, retornar a variável `$lista` alimentada no loop.

Observações:

- A tag provavelmente deveria ser `<br>`. Usar `<br\>` só faz sentido se você estiver fazendo uma página legada em XHTML, ou tiver alguma razão qualquer para processar a saída em XML.
- Quando é para executar uma instrução só no loop, pode simplificar sem os `{ }`:

  ```
  foreach ($tags as $tag) $lista .= $tag->getAttribute('src').'<br>';
  ```

  Claro que você deve permanecer fiel ao estilo que adotou para o resto do código.
- Aqui você duplica a variável aparentemente à toa:

  ```
  $url = $valorUrl;
  $html = file_get_contents($url);
  ```

  Poderia simplesmente fazer:

  ```
  $html = file_get_contents($valorUrl);
  ```
- Em vez dessa supressão de erros em `@$doc->loadHTML($html);`, talvez fosse melhor tratar o erro condicionalmente.